# Extracting information from Log table and put them into column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a following table called "Log".

```
LogID Description  Operator   LogType LogTimeStamp         JobNo  DNo
===== ============ ========   ======= ============         =====  ===
1     Job booked.. John       101     2016-01-01 00:00:00  44111  Null
2     Job booked.. Smith      101     2016-01-01 00:01:00  44112  Null
3     Offered...   (System)   104     2016-01-01 00:01:30  44111  230
4     Rejected...  (System)   105     2016-01-01 00:01:30  44111  230
5     Offered...   (System)   104     2016-01-01 00:02:00  44112  135
6     Offered...   (System)   104     2016-01-01 00:02:36  44111  042
7     Accepted...  (System)   107     2016-01-01 00:02:42  44111  042
8     Accepted...  (System)   107     2016-01-01 00:02:43  44112  135
9     Arrived...   (System)   108     2016-01-01 00:05:30  44111  042
10    POB...       (System)   109     2016-01-01 00:07:00  44111  042
11    Arrived...   (System)   108     2016-01-01 00:08:30  44112  135
12    POB...       (System)   109     2016-01-01 00:08:36  44112  135
13    Complted..   (System)   112     2016-01-01 00:15:00  44111  042
14    Forced Coml. John       1120    2016-01-01 00:20:30  44112  135
```

NOTE: The above (in the description column) is just an extraction. Complete value looks like the following:

```
Job Booked (Pickup time 01:18 Wed 01/06/2016) from Caller 07599999999 calling 300
Job on queue N Gwich accepted by driver on queue WTnC
Arrived at Stop 1
POB at Stop 1
ATTENTION Event Dismissed, 44111 has Rejected a Job
Arrived at Stop 2
POB at Stop 2
Job completed (Approx Paid Mileage = 1.6, Dead Mileage = 1.4)
Job needs to be verified - Account requires all jobs be verified
```

Question: Is it possible to extract data in the following format (in columns):

```
JobNo  DNo  Booked_By  Booked_On Offered_At Accepted_At Arrived_At POB_At   
Completed_At
```

What I've done so far is the following:

```
SELECT 
   [LogID]
  ,[LogTimeStamp]
  ,[LogType]
  ,[JobNo]
  ,[Operator]
  ,[Description]
  ,[TelephoneNumber]
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType = 101 THEN l.LogTimeStamp END AS JobBookedOn
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType = 101 THEN l.Operator END AS JobBookedBy
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType = 107 THEN l.LogTimeStamp END AS JobAcceptedOn
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType = 108 AND l.Description LIKE '%Arrived%Stop 1%' 
THEN l.LogTimeStamp END AS ArrivedAtStop1
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType = 110 AND l.Description LIKE '%POB%Stop 1%' THEN 
l.LogTimeStamp END AS POBAtStop1
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType = 112 THEN l.LogTimeStamp END AS JobCompletedOn
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType =   7 THEN l.LogTimeStamp END AS 
JobForcedCompletedOn
   ,CASE WHEN l.LogType = 301 THEN l.LogTimeStamp END AS CallReceivedOn
FROM [DB_A].[dbo].[Log] AS l
WHERE 
  (LogType = 101 OR
   LogType = 107 OR
   LogType = 108 OR
   LogType = 110 OR
   LogType = 112 OR
   LogType = 7 OR
   LogType = 301)
   AND
   l.JobNo = 4753784
ORDER BY LogTimeStamp DESC
```

What I've achieved so far is presented in this image. Please note it's a truncated image.

[image: Achievement so far]

What can be done to get only one row with the values or null where there is no value.

I've tried looking into PIVOT but couldn't grasp how to do it. Another option looks like CURSOR... Any advise???

Thanks in advance.

EXTRA INFORMATION: A Create command is presented below for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [LogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogTimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LogType] [int] NULL,
    [JobNo] [int] NULL,
    [DrvName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Operator] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [TelephoneNo] [varchar](30) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

SOME DATA TO PLAY WITH (CSV file):

```
LogID,LogTimeStamp,LogType,JobNo,DrvName,OperatorName,Description,TelephoneNumber
93147710,2015-05-25 13:22:14,101,4347551,NULL,John,Job Booked (Pickup time 14:22 Mon 25/05/2015) from Caller 0208317**** calling 300,NULL
93147711,2015-05-25 13:22:14,103,4347551,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue WichTwnC with 5 Priority Points,NULL
93147712,2015-05-25 13:22:14,104,4347551,44,System(Queue),Job offered to driver on queue WichTwnC at position 1,NULL
93147713,2015-05-25 13:22:15,107,4347550,56,System(Queue),Job on queue Cntrl Thmsmd accepted by driver on queue Cntrl Thmsmd,NULL
93147714,2015-05-25 13:22:15,204,NULL,56,System(Queue),Vehicle Car56 booked off queue Cntrl Thmsmd at position 1,NULL
93147715,2015-05-25 13:22:17,112,4347542,37,System(Progress),"Job completed (Approx Paid Mileage = 1.6, Dead Mileage = 0.0)",NULL
93147716,2015-05-25 13:22:18,203,NULL,37,System(Queue),Vehicle Car37 booked onto queue W Thmsmd at position 1,NULL
93147717,2015-05-25 13:22:19,107,4347551,44,System(Queue),Job on queue WichTwnC accepted by driver on queue WichTwnC,NULL
93147718,2015-05-25 13:22:19,204,NULL,44,System(Queue),Vehicle Car44 booked off queue WichTwnC at position 1,NULL
93147726,2015-05-25 13:23:09,104,4347548,79,System(Queue),Job offered to driver on queue Cntrl Thmsmd at position 2,NULL
93147727,2015-05-25 13:23:09,NULL,4347548,70,System(Queue),Job not offered to top Driver on main Queue because attributes don't match,NULL
93147728,2015-05-25 13:23:09,201,NULL,78,System(Signon),"Driver Signed On, Vehicle Car78, PDA serial number PC1EV",NULL
93147729,2015-05-25 13:23:11,116,4347537,4,System(Progress),Job is Late Arriving at the Pickup. Limit 3 min after Pickup Time,NULL
93147730,2015-05-25 13:23:16,107,4347548,79,System(Queue),Job on queue Cntrl Thmsmd accepted by driver on queue Cntrl Thmsmd,NULL
93147731,2015-05-25 13:23:16,204,NULL,79,System(Queue),Vehicle Car79 booked off queue Cntrl Thmsmd at position 2,NULL
93147732,2015-05-25 13:23:22,NULL,4347535,100,System(Progress),Reported: Quotation please.,NULL
93147733,2015-05-25 13:23:44,201,NULL,78,System(Signon),"Driver Signed On, Vehicle Car78, PDA serial number PC1EV",NULL
93147734,2015-05-25 13:23:45,101,4347552,NULL,John,Job Booked (Pickup time 14:23 Mon 25/05/2015),NULL
93147735,2015-05-25 13:23:45,103,4347552,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue WichTwnC with 5 Priority Points,NULL
93147736,2015-05-25 13:23:45,104,4347552,66,System(Queue),Job offered to driver on queue WichTwnC at position 1,NULL
93147737,2015-05-25 13:23:48,107,4347552,66,System(Queue),Job on queue WichTwnC accepted by driver on queue WichTwnC,NULL
93147738,2015-05-25 13:23:48,204,NULL,66,System(Queue),Vehicle Car66 booked off queue WichTwnC at position 1,NULL
93147739,2015-05-25 13:23:51,108,4347547,12,System(Progress),Arrived at Stop 1,NULL
93147740,2015-05-25 13:23:54,110,4347550,56,System(Progress),POB at Stop 1,NULL
93147741,2015-05-25 13:23:58,110,4347547,12,System(Progress),POB at Stop 1,NULL
93147742,2015-05-25 13:24:00,5,4347552,NULL,John,Job Changed,NULL
93147743,2015-05-25 13:24:00,NULL,4347552,NULL,John,Changed Job Driver Notes,NULL
93147744,2015-05-25 13:24:00,NULL,4347552,NULL,System(Progress),Job updated,NULL
93147745,2015-05-25 13:24:01,301,NULL,NULL,TRAINEE2,Received Caller 07789****** calling 300 on line 2,0791112223
93147746,2015-05-25 13:24:13,108,4347537,4,System(Progress),Arrived at Stop 1,NULL
93147747,2015-05-25 13:24:13,119,4347537,4,System(Progress),Vehicle was late by 4 minutes,NULL
93147748,2015-05-25 13:24:13,306,4347537,NULL,System(Progress),Job arrived - Text Message sent to 0784******,0791113335
93147749,2015-05-25 13:24:21,110,4347537,4,System(Progress),POB at Stop 1,NULL
93147750,2015-05-25 13:24:22,108,4347552,66,System(Progress),Arrived at Stop 1,NULL
93147751,2015-05-25 13:24:24,108,4347548,79,System(Progress),Arrived at Stop 1,NULL
93147752,2015-05-25 13:24:24,306,4347548,NULL,System(Progress),Job arrived - Text Message sent to 07580*******,0783336666
93147753,2015-05-25 13:24:26,202,NULL,78,System(Signon),"Driver Signed Off, Vehicle Car78",NULL
93147754,2015-05-25 13:24:49,110,4347548,79,System(Progress),POB at Stop 1,NULL
93147755,2015-05-25 13:24:50,NULL,4347535,100,System(Progress),Reported: Please complete my job,NULL
93147756,2015-05-25 13:25:12,101,4347553,NULL,TRAINEE2,Job Booked (Pickup time 14:25 Mon 25/05/2015) from Caller 0799999999 calling 300,NULL
93147757,2015-05-25 13:25:12,204,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked off queue DockYrd at position 1,NULL
93147758,2015-05-25 13:25:12,203,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked onto queue WichFerry at position 1,NULL
93147759,2015-05-25 13:25:12,103,4347553,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue WichC+Slp with 50 Priority Points,NULL
93147760,2015-05-25 13:25:13,112,4347526,87,System(Progress),"Job completed (Approx Paid Mileage = 6.6, Dead Mileage = 0.0)",NULL
93147761,2015-05-25 13:25:14,110,4347552,66,System(Progress),POB at Stop 1,NULL
93147762,2015-05-25 13:25:15,101,4347554,NULL,John,Job Booked (Pickup time 14:25 Mon 25/05/2015),NULL
93147763,2015-05-25 13:25:15,205,4347549,124,System(Progress),Reported problem: No Show,NULL
93147764,2015-05-25 13:25:16,103,4347554,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue WichTwnC with 5 Priority Points,NULL
93147765,2015-05-25 13:25:16,104,4347554,84,System(Queue),Job offered to driver on queue WichTwnC at position 1,NULL
93147766,2015-05-25 13:25:16,203,NULL,87,System(Queue),Vehicle Car87 booked onto queue Erith at position 1,NULL
93147767,2015-05-25 13:25:19,204,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked off queue WichFerry at position 1,NULL
93147768,2015-05-25 13:25:19,203,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked onto queue WichTwnC at position 10,NULL
93147769,2015-05-25 13:25:20,204,NULL,37,System(Queue),Vehicle Car37 booked off queue W Thmsmd at position 1,NULL
93147770,2015-05-25 13:25:20,203,NULL,37,System(Queue),Vehicle Car37 booked onto queue Cntrl Thmsmd at position 3,NULL
93147771,2015-05-25 13:25:21,107,4347554,84,System(Queue),Job on queue WichTwnC accepted by driver on queue WichTwnC,NULL
93147772,2015-05-25 13:25:21,204,NULL,84,System(Queue),Vehicle Car84 booked off queue WichTwnC at position 1,NULL
93147773,2015-05-25 13:25:24,301,NULL,NULL,John,Received Caller 0794******** calling 300 on line 2,02081114444
93147774,2015-05-25 13:25:39,110,4347551,44,System(Progress),POB at Stop 1,NULL
93147775,2015-05-25 13:25:42,301,NULL,NULL,Julie,Received Caller 07837896457 calling 300 on line 3,02072225555
93147776,2015-05-25 13:25:45,101,4347555,NULL,John,Job Booked (Pickup time 14:25 Mon 25/05/2015) from Caller 079********* calling 300,NULL
93147777,2015-05-25 13:25:46,103,4347555,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue WHAL S HILL with 5 Priority Points,NULL
93147778,2015-05-25 13:25:48,104,4347555,13,System(Queue),Job on queue WHAL S HILL offered to driver on backup queue QE HOSP,NULL
93147779,2015-05-25 13:25:48,5,4347553,NULL,TRAINEE2,Job Changed,NULL
93147780,2015-05-25 13:25:48,NULL,4347553,NULL,TRAINEE2,Changed Job Driver Notes,NULL
93147781,2015-05-25 13:25:49,301,NULL,NULL,John,Received Caller 07580****** calling 300 on line 2,02076668888
93147782,2015-05-25 13:25:51,301,NULL,NULL,TRAINEE2,Received Caller 07837****** calling 203 on line 3,07865465445
93147783,2015-05-25 13:25:51,204,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked off queue WichTwnC at position 9,NULL
93147784,2015-05-25 13:25:51,203,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked onto queue WichFerry at position 1,NULL
93147787,2015-05-25 13:25:53,NULL,4347535,100,System(Progress),Reported: Please complete my job,NULL
93147788,2015-05-25 13:25:54,NULL,4347553,NULL,System(Queue),Job removed from queue WichC+Slp because it was modified,NULL
93147791,2015-05-25 13:25:55,103,4347553,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue WichC+Slp with 52 Priority Points,NULL
93147792,2015-05-25 13:26:05,204,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked off queue WichFerry at position 1,NULL
93147793,2015-05-25 13:26:05,203,NULL,14,System(Queue),Vehicle Car14 booked onto queue Woolwich Low at position 1,NULL
93147794,2015-05-25 13:26:06,101,4347556,NULL,John,Job Booked (Pickup time 14:26 Mon 25/05/2015) from Caller 075******** calling 300,NULL
93147795,2015-05-25 13:26:07,103,4347556,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue Cntrl Thmsmd with 5 Priority Points,NULL
93147796,2015-05-25 13:26:07,104,4347556,70,System(Queue),Job offered to driver on queue Cntrl Thmsmd at position 1,NULL
93147797,2015-05-25 13:26:08,7,4347535,100,Julie,Job Forced Complete. Reason given: CC,NULL
93147798,2015-05-25 13:26:08,301,NULL,NULL,John,Received Caller 02083178728 calling 300 on line 2,02083178999
93147799,2015-05-25 13:26:09,107,4347556,70,System(Queue),Job on queue Cntrl Thmsmd accepted by driver on queue Cntrl Thmsmd,NULL
93147800,2015-05-25 13:26:09,204,NULL,70,System(Queue),Vehicle Car70 booked off queue Cntrl Thmsmd at position 1,NULL
93147801,2015-05-25 13:26:11,105,4347555,13,System(Queue),Job rejected by driver; Job remains on queue WHAL S HILL,NULL
93147802,2015-05-25 13:26:20,6,4347549,NULL,Julie,Operator contacted passenger by telephone,07507999486
93147803,2015-05-25 13:26:23,205,4347549,124,System(Progress),Reported problem: No Show,NULL
93147804,2015-05-25 13:26:26,108,4347554,84,System(Progress),Arrived at Stop 1,NULL
93147805,2015-05-25 13:26:29,101,4347557,NULL,John,Job Booked (Pickup time 14:26 Mon 25/05/2015) from Caller 0208317**** calling 300,NULL
93147806,2015-05-25 13:26:29,103,4347557,NULL,System(Queue),Job added to queue WichTwnC with 5 Priority Points,NULL
93147807,2015-05-25 13:26:29,104,4347557,36,System(Queue),Job offered to driver on queue WichTwnC at position 2,NULL
93147808,2015-05-25 13:26:29,NULL,4347557,22,System(Queue),Job not offered to top Driver on main Queue because the Account is restricted,NULL
93147809,2015-05-25 13:26:29,112,4347538,41,System(Progress),"Job completed (Approx Paid Mileage = 3.9, Dead Mileage = 0.0)",NULL
93147810,2015-05-25 13:26:30,203,NULL,41,System(Queue),Vehicle Car41 booked onto queue Up Belveder at position 1,NULL
93147811,2015-05-25 13:26:31,203,NULL,100,System(Queue),Vehicle Car100 booked onto queue Blackheath at position 1,NULL
93147812,2015-05-25 13:26:31,127,4347553,NULL,System(Queue),Job is high enough priority to override normal Queue processing,NULL
93147813,2015-05-25 13:26:37,NULL,4347547,NULL,TRAINEE2,"ATTENTION Event Dismissed, 36 has Rejected a Job",NULL
93147814,2015-05-25 13:26:37,NULL,4347547,NULL,TRAINEE2,"ATTENTION Event Dismissed, 66 has Rejected a Job",NULL
93147815,2015-05-25 13:26:37,NULL,4347548,NULL,TRAINEE2,"ATTENTION Event Dismissed, 79 has Rejected a Job",NULL
93147816,2015-05-25 13:26:37,NULL,4347547,NULL,TRAINEE2,"ATTENTION Event Dismissed, 44 has Rejected a Job",NULL
```

Comment: Its unclear what you mean.  Do you want to group rows with same rownumber?  That would make several occasions where the query would have to chose which value is the right one, eg where there are 2 rows with values in JobAcceptedOn..  Which one is right..

Could you display anexample of how you'd like the result in the picture to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are trying to do:

[image]

Please note that my answer is missing `DNo` as this field was not provided. But, assuming that `DNo` has a 1:1 relationship with `JobNo`, then you simply add it to the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.

If so then you are almost there:

```
 SELECT [JobNo],
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 101
                   THEN l.LogTimeStamp
               END) AS JobBookedOn,
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 101
                   THEN l.[OperatorName]
               END) AS JobBookedBy,
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 107
                   THEN l.LogTimeStamp
               END) AS JobAcceptedOn,
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 108
                        AND l.Description LIKE '%Arrived%Stop 1%'
                   THEN l.LogTimeStamp
               END) AS ArrivedAtStop1,
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 110
                        AND l.Description LIKE '%POB%Stop 1%'
                   THEN l.LogTimeStamp
               END) AS POBAtStop1,
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 112
                   THEN l.LogTimeStamp
               END) AS JobCompletedOn,
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 7
                   THEN l.LogTimeStamp
               END) AS JobForcedCompletedOn,
           MAX(CASE
                   WHEN l.LogType = 301
                   THEN l.LogTimeStamp
               END) AS CallReceivedOn
    FROM [dbo].[Log] AS l
    WHERE(LogType = 101
          OR LogType = 107
          OR LogType = 108
          OR LogType = 110
          OR LogType = 112
          OR LogType = 7
          OR LogType = 301)
         AND l.JobNo = 4347551
    GROUP BY [JobNo];
```

see above results.

Comment: Thanks Kamran Farzami. The solution works like a charm. Thanks again.